# Access database UPDATE table with subquery

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

I never should've expected that knowing mySQL I'd be safe using Access.

I have two tables: users and scores
users table contains: id(auto increment primary key), username, password, etc..
scoers table contains: id(number - foreign key to users.id), highScore

I've previously asked help for INSERT command, which now works as it should. Now I've got issues with a similar UPDATE command.

The non-working command looks like this:

```
string updateCommand = @"UPDATE scores
                         SET
                         id = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = @username),
                         highScore = @score
                         WHERE highScore = (SELECT MIN(highScore) FROM scores);";
```

which throws a: `Operation must use an updateable query.`

To rationalize what I'm trying to accomplish here: I'm INSERT-ing high scores until I reach 10 scores in the table, afterwards instead of adding any new scores and filling up the database needlessly I decided It'd be more sensible to just "overwrite" the currently lowest score using UPDATE.

I am supplied a username and the high score and since the `scores` table contains only `id` I need to reach the id of the current user so that's what the first subquery is doing, the second subquery in the WHERE clause is to specify which score to replace (though there is possibly a bug here if there are multiple people with the lowest score, any ideas how to fix that?)

I've also tried using OUTER RIGHT JOIN like this:

```
string updateCommand = @"UPDATE scores
                            OUTER RIGHT JOIN users ON scores.id = users.id
                            SET
                            scores.id = users.id,
                            scores.highScore = @score
                            WHERE (highScore = (SELECT MIN(highScore) FROM scores)) AND (username = @username);";
```

With no luck(I get a generic `Syntax error in UPDATE statement.`).

Browsing the net I've found that I possibly "can't" use subqueries in UPDATE statements but I seem to find conflicting opinions on the matter.

I've also tried using the DLookup function in place of subqueries like:

```
@"...
id = DLookup(""id"", ""users"", ""username = @username""),
...
WHERE highScore = DLookup(""MIN(highScore)"", ""scores"");";
```

elipses represent extraneous code which is identical to the code above.

Also as a last resort I've tried dividing into multiple queries however userId query which looks like this:

```
string userIdQuery = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = @username"
```

seems to return a null judging by the NullReferenceException i recieve (`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`) when trying to use the variable userId after I've done this:

```
int userId = 0;
userId = (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

I'm supposed to get an integer however I get a null I think. The almost identical query for getting the minimum highscore works flawlessly and the int variable is filled with the correct value so I'm assuming that hte problem is in the query itself somehow. I've tried adding single quotes around the `@username` parameter assuming that it might not be recognizing the string but it seems that's not it.

Phew.. took me a while to write this. Anyone got any ideas on how to make this all work? If you need more info let me know.

Comment: @HansUp I've tried designing it in access and gotten a command that does an inner join and all it seems to do in access is select the entry with the lowest id without actually changing anthing. The command looks like this: `UPDATE users INNER JOIN scores ON users.id = scores.id 
SET scores.id = (SELECT [users].[id] FROM [users] WHERE [users].[username] = "Member"), scores.highScore = 1234
WHERE (((scores.highScore)=(SELECT Min( [scores].[highScore] ) FROM [scores] )));`

Comment: @HansUp I've gone quiet because I had some errands to run so I had to go away for a while. I don't quite understand your suggestion. Do you mean that in the subquery I should somehow extract the scores row that I'm updating on? Or that I should somehow do that beforehand(extract it into variables and then update on values?). If it's the latter then I see no use for username selection since I only wish to change the score and user id it's linking to

Comment: @HansUp Also trying to use the command in the second comment I get `Must use an updateable query` error, while I can't get DMin to work in access directly, much less through ASP.NET. In criteria I've tried `= DMin('highScore', 'scores')` , `= DMin( [scores].[highScore], [scores] ) ` , `= DMin( "[scores].[highScore]", "[scores]" ) ` with no luck, I keep getting `The expression you entered contains invalid syntax.` error.

Comment: I see I communicated poorly, and I apologize for that.  At this point, rather than trying to sort out the confusion, I'll suggest you tackle this with `SELECT` queries to retrieve the values you need, and then a parameter query for the `UPDATE`.  Use the SELECTed values for the `UPDATE` parameters.  That approach is not as slick as a single `UPDATE` which does everything, but should be easier to implement.

Comment: @HansUp I've found a working solution for this this morning, I'll post the correct answer soon. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

So after some messing around I've found out the causes of my troubles. The bad side is that I increased the amount of code so that I'd avoid subqueries as much as possible since, at least from my experience, Access doesn't really like the use of subqueries in `UPDATE` or `INSERT` commands.

What I did first is split the command into 3 separate ones:

- `"SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?;"` - To get the id of the user whose score 
  I'm putting in the database.
- `@"SELECT scores.id, scores.highScore, scores.dateTime FROM scores WHERE (((scores.highScore)=DMin(""highScore"",""scores"")));"` - which gets the id, high score 
  and time when the entry was... well entered, of the lowest score currently in the high scores list. Thanks to a suggestion from [HansUp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77335/hansup) I used `DMin` function instead of a subquery with `MIN` to avoid the `Must use an updateable query` error. The extraneous parentheses are due to Access since this command was generated by the Access query designer and I'm too afraid to change anything lest I break it.
- `@"UPDATE scores SET scores.id = ?, scores.highScore = ?, scores.[dateTime] = Now() WHERE (((scores.id)=?) AND ((scores.highScore)=?) AND ((scores.dateTime)=?));"` - The update command itself, not much to say here except that it takes the previously extracted data and uses it as values for the command.

One thing I noticed is that even if I got the command working the `.ExecuteNonQuery()` would always return 0 rows affected. After poking around I found out that named parameters for commands in ASP.NET / C# don't always work and that instead `?` should be used instead. It's kind of inconvenient but I can't complain too much.